# Is this property an isomorphic characterization of $\ell_1(\Gamma)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite set. Then every $(x_i)_{i\in\Gamma}\in \ell_1(\Gamma)$ has at most a countable number of components $x_i\neq 0$. 
As a consequence, every separable subspace $M$ of $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ is contained in an isometric copy of $\ell_1$ which is $1$-complemented in $\ell_1(\Gamma)$. 
Indeed, there exists a countable subset $I$ of $\Gamma$ such that for each $(x_i)\in M$, $x_i=0$ for $i\in \Gamma\setminus I$, thus $M$ is contained in $\ell_1(I)\subset  \ell_1(\Gamma)$.

QUESTION: Suppose that $E$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space such that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, each separable subspace $M$ of $E$ is contained in a $(1+\varepsilon)$-isometric copy of $\ell_1$ in $E$ which is $(1+\varepsilon)$-complemented in $E$.

Is $E$ isomorphic to $\ell_1(\Gamma)$ for some $\Gamma$?

Comment: Yes. $E$ is $\cal{L}_1$-$(1+\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon >0$, hence is isometrically isomorphic to $L_1(\mu)$ for some measure $\mu$, and $\mu$ must be purely atomic since, e.g., your hypothesis implies that $E$ has the Schur property.

Comment: And what happens replacing $(1+\varepsilon)$ by a fixed constant $C$ with $1<C<\infty$ in both places?

Comment: I am not sure.  Maybe Lewis and Stegall proved that such a space must embed  into $\ell_(\Gamma)$ (because $E$ has the Radon-Nikodym property). Even if that is correct, there is still the problem of seeing that $E$ is complementably embeddable into $\ell_1(\Gamma)$. Probably no one has ever looked at this. $$$$ Does there exist $X\subset Y$ s.t. every separable subspace of $X$ is contained in a separable subspace of $X$ that is complemented in $Y$, yet $X$ is not complemented in $Y$?

Comment: Let $X=c_0(\omega_1)$ and $Y=C(\omega_1)$.  Clearly every separable subspace of $X$ is contained in a larger separable subspace of $X$ that is 2-complemented in $Y$.  Is $X$ complemented in $Y$? My guess is that standard arguments give a negative answer, but I have not tried to check it out.

Comment: @BillJohnson, actually it will be complemented. See Theorem 1.1 in https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/S0024611502013618

Comment: @BillJohnson, however there is a compact space $K$ for which Bill's idea works. Indeed, Marciszewski constructed an Eberlein compact space $K$ such that $C(K)$ contains an uncomplemented copy of $c_0(\Gamma)$ (See Remark 2 in https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/studia-mathematica/all/156/3/90609/on-banach-spaces-c-k-isomorphic-to-c-0-mit-gamma) As $K$ is Eberlein, $C(K)$ is WCG, hence it has the separable complementation property. In particular, every copy of $c_0$ in $C(K)$ is complemented.

Comment: Thanks, Tomek. I am glad that I did not try to check out my wrong guess!

Comment: From my paper with Odell (http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1974__28_1_37_0.pdf) one can deduce that Manuel's questions have  positive answers if you replace $\ell_1$ by $\ell_p$, $1<p<\infty$. The argument does not work for $\ell_1$; maybe that is why Manuel asked this question.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was trying to show that a separably projective space $E$ is  isomorphic to $\ell_1(\Gamma)$. The case $E$ separable is easy, and the question tries to know what happens if $E$ has the separable complementation property.